# AngularsJS list and edit with 2 controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I try to do my first angularjs application, but i have a problem. I have 2 controllers (and i would like to keep 2): the first to list items, the second to edit or create an item.

When I save an item, or create a new item, i can't edit another or create another, after to do one action the form can't load or save... The problem seems to be this line :

```
$scope.editPlace = {};
```

But I don't understand why...

DEMO :

http://jsfiddle.net/cxL7qmke/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="mapApp">
    <div ng-controller="EditPlaceCtrl">
        <form name="editPlaceForm">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="title">Title:</label>
                <input id="title" type="text" ng-model="editPlace.title">
                <input type="hidden" ng-model="editPlace.id" />
                <button type="submit" ng-click="savePlace()">Save</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <section ng-controller="PlaceCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="place in places">
                <label>{{place.title}} <a href="#" ng-click="edit(place.id)">edit</a></label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

JS :

```
var mapApp = angular.module('mapApp', []);
mapApp.controller('PlaceCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, placeService) {
    $scope.places = placeService.getAll();
    $scope.edit = function (id) {
        $rootScope.editPlace = angular.copy(placeService.get(id));
    }
});

mapApp.controller('EditPlaceCtrl', function ($scope, placeService) {
    $scope.savePlace = function () {
        placeService.save($scope.editPlace);
        $scope.editPlace = {};
    }
});

mapApp.service('placeService', function ($filter) {
    var uid = 3;
    var places = [
        { id: 1, title: 'Item1', lat: 43.123, lng: -89.123 },
        { id: 2, title: 'Item2', lat: 43.321, lng: -89.321 }
    ];
    this.getAll = function () {
        return places;
    }
    this.get = function (id) {
        var place, i;
        for (i in places) {
            if (places[i].id === id) {
                return places[i];
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
    this.save = function (place) {
        if (place.id == null) {
            place.id = this.uid++;
            places.push(place);
        } else {
            for (i in places) {
                if (places[i].id == place.id) {
                    places[i] = place;
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made few changes and seems to work for me please see here

http://jsfiddle.net/m9bevovy/

in your service I've added

```
this.newPlace = {};

this.setNew = function (id) {

        this.newPlace = this.get(id);
};
```

and your controllers :

```
mapApp.controller('PlaceCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, placeService) {
    $scope.places = placeService.getAll();
    $scope.edit = function (id) {
        placeService.setNew(id);
    }
});

mapApp.controller('EditPlaceCtrl', function ($scope, placeService) {
    $scope.placeService = placeService;
    $scope.savePlace = function () {
        placeService.save($scope.placeService.newPlace);
        $scope.placeService.newPlace = {};
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using both `$scope` and `$rootScope` to hold the reference to `editPlace`.

If you want to use the `$rootScope`, use this in your `savePlace` function:

```
$rootScope.editPlace = {};
```

Instead of:

```
$scope.editPlace = {};
```

Here`s the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxL7qmke/2/)

Comment: I will add that `$scope` should also be replaced with `$rootScope` when calling `placeService.save(...)`.

Of course, you will need to take `$rootScope` as a dependency in the constructor for `EditPlaceCtrl`.

Comment: It's better, but when i begin to create a new item, i can edit other when I click to "edit".

Comment: When you create a new item, you need to assign an id to it, otherwise you won't be able to edit the new item.